# Can't make video call on android 6 with quickblox

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I m trying to build video chat app with quickblox v2.5.

My chat app working well on iOS9.2 and android 4+, 5+.

But it does not work on android 6. :(

I used Nexus 5 and Samsung galaxy s4, s5.

When I use Nexus5 for the test, it working well between iOS to android, android-android.

But I can't make a video call between android to iOS. (only work audio call).

When I use Samsung galax, it's not worked on all cases (ios-android, android-android, android-ios).

Few days of googling and debugging, I found that this issue happened when to create a session with the opponent.

```
QBRTCSession newSessionWithOpponents = rtcClient.createNewSessionWithOpponents(
                getOpponentsIds(opponents), qbConferenceType);
```

Following is part of logcat.

> 03-06 14:45:31.901 15892-16599/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/VideoRendererGui: VideoRendererGui.onSurfaceChanged: 1056 x 1056
>   03-06 14:45:31.901 15892-16599/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/VideoRendererGui: ID: 0. YuvImageRenderer.setScreenSize: 1056 x 1056
>   03-06 14:45:31.903 15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/AudioRecordJni: EnableBuiltInAEC@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:31.904
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/WebRtcAudioRecord:
>   EnableBuiltInAEC(true) 03-06 14:45:31.908
>   15892-16574/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.PeerFactoryManager: Peer connection factory initiated from
>   thread1060 03-06 14:45:32.320
>   15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: onLocalStreamNeedAdd for opponent 2436257
>   03-06 14:45:32.321 15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBMediaStreamManager: Init local media stream 03-06
>   14:45:32.321 15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBMediaStreamManager: Add video stream 03-06 14:45:32.323
>   15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: onError in peer channel for opponent
>   2436257, No device for video input was found 03-06 14:45:32.323
>   15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: Request Looper execute. 03-06 14:45:32.323
>   15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: POST.Run on thread:1056 for QBRTCClient
>   03-06 14:45:32.323 15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel: Call hangUp to opponent 2436257 03-06
>   14:45:32.323 15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel: close 03-06 14:45:32.323
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.PeerChannelLifeCycleTimers: Stop
>   DialingTimer 03-06 14:45:32.323
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.PeerChannelLifeCycleTimers: Stop WaitTimer
>   03-06 14:45:32.323 15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.PeerChannelLifeCycleTimers: Stop
>   DisconnectTimer 03-06 14:45:32.323
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: Request Looper execute. 03-06 14:45:32.324
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: POST.Run on thread:1062 for QBPeerChannel
>   03-06 14:45:32.325 15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel: Closing peer connection start. 03-06
>   14:45:32.326 15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.SDPObserver:: SDP successfully created 
>   03-06 14:45:32.326 15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.RTCMediaUtils: generateLocalDescription:  audioCodec=ISAC
>   03-06 14:45:32.328 15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.RTCMediaUtils: Found ISAC rtpmap 103, prefer at m=audio 9
>   RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 127 126 03-06 14:45:32.328
>   15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.RTCMediaUtils: Change media description: m=audio 9
>   RTP/SAVPF 103 111 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 127 126 03-06 14:45:32.328
>   15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.RTCMediaUtils: generateLocalDescription:  videoCodec=VP8
>   03-06 14:45:32.330 15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.RTCMediaUtils: Found VP8 rtpmap 100, prefer at m=video 9
>   RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117 96 03-06 14:45:32.330
>   15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.RTCMediaUtils: Change media description: m=video 9
>   RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117 96 03-06 14:45:32.331
>   15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.PCObserver:: onIceConnectionChange to CLOSED
>   03-06 14:45:32.331 15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.PCObserver:: onIceGatheringChange to
>   COMPLETE 03-06 14:45:32.331
>   15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.PCObserver:: onSignalingChange to CLOSED
>   03-06 14:45:32.332 15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: onChannelConnectionClosed for opponent
>   2436257 03-06 14:45:32.332
>   15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: Request Looper execute. 03-06 14:45:32.332
>   15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: POST.Run on thread:1056 for QBRTCClient
>   03-06 14:45:32.332 15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: Request Looper stop. On QBPeerChannel
>   03-06 14:45:32.332 15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: Looper thread finished. 03-06 14:45:32.332
>   15892-16578/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel: onExecutorStop.PeerChannel succesfully
>   stoped 03-06 14:45:32.333
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/ConversationFragment: getViewForOpponent holder user id is : 2436257
>   03-06 14:45:32.333 15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: Check is session need close 03-06
>   14:45:32.333 15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: Session isNeedToClose true 03-06
>   14:45:32.333 15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: closeSession 03-06 14:45:32.333
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: Request Looper execute. 03-06 14:45:32.334
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/SessionClosedListener: onSessionStartClose 03-06 14:45:32.334
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: Request Looper execute. 03-06 14:45:32.334
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: POST.Run on thread:1060 for
>   PeerFactoryManager 03-06 14:45:32.334
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession.SessionWaitingTimers: Stop WaitTimer 03-06
>   14:45:32.334 15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: Notify sesions callbacks in count of:2 03-06
>   14:45:32.335 15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: Request Looper execute. 03-06 14:45:32.335
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: POST.Run on thread:1060 for
>   PeerFactoryManager 03-06 14:45:32.335
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/RTCClient.:
>   onSessionClosed 03-06 14:45:32.335
>   15892-16406/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: EXECUTE.Run on thread:1056 for QBRTCClient
>   03-06 14:45:32.335 15892-16574/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBMediaStreamManager: Video source start dispose 03-06
>   14:45:32.335 15892-16574/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.QBMediaStreamManager: Video source is null 03-06
>   14:45:32.335 15892-16574/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.PeerFactoryManager: start dispose Peer factory 03-06
>   14:45:32.336 15892-15892/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/CallActivity: Session 31edba93-27cb-4e51-82a1-f8e0839e6aeb start
>   stop session 03-06 14:45:32.336
>   15892-15892/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/CallActivity: Stop
>   session 03-06 14:45:32.384
>   15892-15892/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/OpponentsFragment:
>   onCreate() from OpponentsFragment 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/OpenSLESPlayer:
>   Terminate@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/OpenSLESPlayer:
>   StopPlayout@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/AudioRecordJni:
>   Terminate@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/AudioRecordJni:
>   StopRecording@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/AudioManager:
>   Close@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/WebRtcAudioManager:
>   dispose@[name=Thread-1067, id=1067] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/AudioRecordJni:
>   ~dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/AudioRecordJni:
>   Terminate@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/AudioRecordJni:
>   StopRecording@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/JVM:
>   GlobalRef::dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/JVM:
>   NativeRegistration::dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/JVM:
>   JNIEnvironment::dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/JVM:
>   AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded::dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/OpenSLESPlayer:
>   dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/OpenSLESPlayer:
>   Terminate@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/OpenSLESPlayer:
>   StopPlayout@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/OpenSLESPlayer:
>   DestroyAudioPlayer 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/OpenSLESPlayer:
>   DestroyMix 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/OpenSLESPlayer:
>   DestroyEngine 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/AudioManager:
>   ~dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/AudioManager:
>   Close@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/AudioManager:
>   JavaAudioManager::dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/JVM:
>   GlobalRef::dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/JVM:
>   NativeRegistration::dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/JVM:
>   JNIEnvironment::dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/JVM:
>   AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded::dtor@[tid=16591] 03-06 14:45:32.693
>   15892-16591/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/JVM: Detaching
>   thread from JVM 03-06 14:45:32.696
>   15892-16592/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc W/art: Native thread
>   exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread (maybe it's going to
>   use a pthread_key_create destructor?):
>   Thread[42,tid=16592,Native,Thread*=0xaeb55500,peer=0x94f730a0,"signaling_threa
>   - 16592"] 03-06 14:45:32.699 15892-16574/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.PeerFactoryManager: dispose Peer factory done 03-06
>   14:45:32.699 15892-16574/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: Request Looper stop. On PeerFactoryManager
>   03-06 14:45:32.699 15892-16574/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc
>   D/RTCClient.LooperExecutor: Looper thread finished.

On this line, the app crashed. So call activity can't launch.

Anyone, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should Request Permissions at RunTime.
**CAMERA** Permission in your case.
Please read more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: Hi Vladimir
Thanks for your quick reply.
I requested permission at runtime.
Also I've tested with manual grant permission.
But it's not worked. :(

Comment: @YaborHabarov have you tried to ask Storage Permissions as well? And there are a lot of logs, but I did not find something like error log, could you post final Error log (crush log)?

Comment: Vladimir, Thanks for your reply again.

I gave following permission to my app.

"Camera", "MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS", "RECORD_AUDIO", "INTERNET", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "VIBRATE", "READ_PHONE_STATE", "ACCESS_WIFI_STATE".
You can find full logcat file on here.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8cbaxnqg21ywob/log1.txt?dl=0)
Hope to hearing from you soon.
Thanks